# Should i disable triggers when force reinstalling packages in ubuntu (to repair corrupted exectables)

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, reinstall

I want to reinstall some selected packages on my ubuntu server (lucid). I'm planning on running `cat packages.txt | xargs apt-get --reinstall install` to restore some executables I think may have become corrupted. My question is, should I use dpkg's option to not run triggers. This would I presume specifically prevent the configuration triggers from running, so I wouldn't trash my config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So firstly, I can't find a way to access dkpg's options from apt-get. Secondly, I ran without disabling triggers with no ill effects. Short answer, no; you do not need to disable triggers.